# GetProcessAffinityMask returns ProcessAffinty and SystemAffinity as -1 (overflow)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

The process is not running as WOW64, its running as x64 in an x64 environment.
the code is as follows

```
    DWORD64 dwProcessAffinity, dwSystemAffinity;
    GetProcessAffinityMask(GetCurrentProcess(), &dwProcessAffinity, &dwSystemAffinity);
```

As confirmation [IsWow64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684139%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is returning false. The environment created has the number of processors more than a hundred.

Comment: have you tried declaring dwProcessAffinity and dwSystemAffinity as DWORD_PTR instead? What does GetLastError() return?

Comment: doesn't DWORD_PTR simply runs as DWORD64 in an x64 environment?
and these are the two things that i haven't tested yet. Should i expect some change with DWORD_PTR ?

Comment: Is -1 actually overflow, or does -1 really mean 0xffffffffffffffff, as in all 64 processors?  How many processors are present?  What version of Windows are you running?

If you really have more than a hundred processors, then I presume you are running Win7+ (or Server 2008 R2) and should be calling GetProcessGroupAffinity instead of GetProcessAffinityMask.

Comment: well i got more information where this is running, the number of physical processors are 4 and through Hyper-Threading the number of logical are about 132. The windows running is 2003 R2.

Comment: @Brian can you please post your comment as it is the correct answer, but one question as to how does 0xffffffffffffffff mean all 64 processors, since its a bit mask. The problem that i figured out is, the number of physical processor is 40(Yes i was given wrong information) and through HT it becomes 80 which is larger than 64, so it is a fault in two places, one is windows 2003 doesnt support more than 64 (physical) processors and with HT enabled the OS cannot differentiate between physical and logical(HT)

Comment: @Brian can you please post your comment as the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value of GetProcessAffinityMask is a BOOL, so if the call has returned TRUE, then the call has succeeded.  There are two masks, one for the process affinity and another for the system affinity.  Each bit in the mask corresponds to a processor.  For example, the mask 0x10 means processor 4 and the mask 0x03 means processors 0 and 1.  A mask of -1 (0xffffffffffffffff) has 64 bits set, one for each processor 0 through 63.  By using a DWORD_PTR (and not a DWORD64), there was probably an attempt (by the original developers) to ensure later programmers view the result as a unsigned hex sequence and not as a signed integer, and furthermore this type results in sizing the mask appropriately (see next paragraph).

When Windows 2003 was being developed, it was exceedingly rare to have a system of even 32 processors, so placing the limit of 32 (for 32-bit versions) and 64 (for 64-bit versions) was reasonable.  Even in the 2008 timeframe, there were still debates about raising the processor limit for Windows 2008 R2, which now supports 256, but could go higher.  Running Windows 2003 is using technology that is a decade old, so one can expect some limitations regarding what were new technologies at the time.

Hyperthreading (HT) is an interesting technology.  There is some benefit to adding the additional hardware to support another logical thread.  Understand that for the OS, there is no distinguishing between the two logical processors, in that one cannot say X is the physical processor and Y is the HT "add-on".  The hardware treats X and Y as equal partners to the shared resources, and so the OS sees them equally.

As the final uncertainty into your situation, I cannot tell you what subset of the 80 logical processors that Windows 2003 will be using.  It might take 32 HT pairs or it might take the physical 40 and include 24 logical HT units.  You could help answer that by running [GetLogicalProcessorInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683194%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Awesome answer and great explanation but wouldn't 0x10 mean processor 5 since in bits it will be 00010000

Comment: It would, except processor numbers start at 0.